# OS updates related information for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, api, updates

Is it possible to obtain an information about availability latest Mac OS X updates via any API? I'd like to know if all available updates were installed on a user's Mac before running some functional. For example: user mac has 10.8.1 installed and I need to check is it latest version of the OS or not. Also I need to check that all security updates were installed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `softwareupdate` command.

> Software Update checks for new and updated versions of your software
>        based on information about your computer and current software.